# Minimize litter box smell: upstairs or downstairs?

Tags: cats

I have 3 cats and we are moving into a two story house.  We are considering two main locations for one or two large uncovered litterboxes: upstairs or downstairs.  Which location would minimize the smell?

Does smell tend to rise or fall?  Does it depend on the temperature?

Does first or second story not really matter?

We will probably have 2 uncovered litter boxes on one floor and 1 covered [Litter Robot](http://www.litter-robot.com/) (which the cats use about half the time) on the other floor.  I am not concerned about the covered litter robot (which has minimal smell); I am just concerned with the smell of the large uncovered litter boxes.

Comment: The amount of smell is more likely due to litter type. Though where do you spend most time? The closer you are to it the more you'll smell it.

Comment: If you *really* want to improve smell, do both. Furthermore, you should increase the number of litterboxes; 3 cats should not share 1 box -- the recommended amount is at least cats +1 (so in your case, 4).  Even going from automated boxes to manual, an increase of one box cuts down the smell immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smells diffuse throughout the air, moving outward in all directions. So from that point of view, upstairs or downstairs doesn't matter.

However, the walls will help to contain the smell somewhat, so that whichever floor the litter box is on, the smell won't be as strong on the other floor. For that reason, assuming you are more likely to entertain guests downstairs, I'd put the open boxes upstairs, and the litter robot downstairs.